# possible data loss in designer of a vb.net form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, dataset, designer

I opened Visual Studio 2013 and loaded my project but I got this error

```
The designer cannot process the code at line 28: Me.AgentDB_DataSet = New appli.agentDB_DataSet() The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and should not be manually modified. Please remove any changes and try opening the designer again.
```

Here is a picture of the error:

[image: error message]

I made a copy from the application, and clicked on ignore and continue ... then it loaded my form empty all controls were lost 
please help me I'm scared of loosing all the work.

This is the list of errors I get when I try to compile:

[image: list of errors]

Comment: This is why committing regularly to Git is a good thing, try to re-open VS, if it doesn't work you can eventually try to comment the faulty lines until it works, you'll have to re-create these objects though.

Comment: does this mean I have to re-do aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaall the work again ???